# How to prove this limit of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits

suppose there exists a $k>0$ and two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ where $n$ from $1$ to $\infty$ such that two sequences $(a_n=b_n)$ for all $n>k$. I want to show that if $(a_n)$ converge, $(b_n)$ also converges.

Since $a_n$ is convergent, so there exists a $N>0$ such that for all $\epsilon$, $|a_n-L| < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$. For this prove, I don't know if I can just pick $N\geq k$ and conclude that $|b_n-L| < \epsilon$ for all $n>N\geq k$ because $(a_n=b_n)$ for all $n>k$

How do I continue this proof to make it correct? Thank you

Comment: In the  first sentence you can replace $N$ by anything larger. Also 'for all $\epsilon >0$' should come before 'there exist $N$'.

Comment: Any estimate which holds for all $n>N$ will also hold for all $n>\max\{N,k\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You recite the definition of convergence wrong.
You do not have an $N$ such that for all $\varepsilon$, but you have for every $\varepsilon$ an $N$.

We want to show that $(b_n)$ convergece to the same limit as $(a_n)$ does.

So let $a_n\to a$. And $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary.

Then we have to discuss $|b_n-a|$. As there is a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a_n=b_n$ for every $n>k$.

As $a_n\to a$ we find $N$ with $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq N$.

Now let $N'=\max\{k+1,N\}$. As $a_n=b_n$ for every $n\geq k+1$ anyways this concludes the proof, since then $|b_n-a|=|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I like the use of the word 'recite' in this answer.

Comment: @fwd Is it wrong?

Comment: no, I meant that the word recite reminds me of how I recall the definition myself. I literally recite it in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

If $N$ satisfies the condition of convergence of $a_n$, then so does any larger number, and you can replace $N$ by $\max(N,K)$, which will satisfy the condition of convergence for $b_n$.